# How do I set a variable from casper.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to set a value from within casper.evaluate() that I will check later to run a test on, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
isArticleOrReview = false;
casper.waitFor(function check() { //here I'm just waiting for jQuery to load
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return jQuery.fn.jquery == '1.2.6';
    });
}, function then() { //once jQuery has been loaded, do this stuff
    this.evaluate(function() {
        isArticleOrReview =  (jQuery('body').hasClass('node-type-review') || jQuery('body').hasClass('node-type-article'));
        __utils__.echo('isArticleOrReview ' + isArticleOrReview);
    });
});
casper.then(function(){
    casper.test.info('isArticleOrReview ' + isArticleOrReview);
});
```

For output I get:

```
isArticleOrReview true
isArticleOrReview false
```

I want this to read:

```
isArticleOrReview true
isArticleOrReview true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evaluate` is sandboxed. The evaluated function has no access to the surrounding code, nor does surrounding code have access to the evaluated function. Here is a simpler example from PhantomJS (Casper's `evaluate` uses that underneath):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com/', function(status) {
  var titleVar = "NOT SET";

  var titleReturn = page.evaluate(function() {
    // This would result in an error:
    // console.log('Variable in evaluate:', titleVar);
    // ReferenceError: Can't find variable: titleVar

    titleVar = document.title;
    return document.title;
  });

  console.log('Return value from evaluate:', titleReturn);
  console.log('Variable post evaluate:', titleVar);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

As you found out, this will print

```
Return value from evaluate: Google
Variable post evaluate: NOT SET
```

and if you uncomment the `console.log` line inside `evaluate`, you will see `evaluate` crash and burn, since the variable does not exist.

Thus, you can only pass values through `evaluate` parameters and return values (and only those that are JSON-serialisable):

```
isArticleOrReview = this.evaluate(function() {
  return (jQuery('body').hasClass('node-type-review') || jQuery('body').hasClass('node-type-article'));
});
```